# Sending simple type from HTML form to ASP API

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-web-api

I am having troubles with sending a simple double number from form to ASP API.

When I submit the form, I firstly need to remove Submit button to avoid sending a redundant 'submit=Submit' value to API controller.

As I have read in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-1) article, I set the name of my input field to be empty. So if I check the http request in Developer mode, the body of sent data looks like so '=value'. My method parameter is decorated with [FromBody] attribute.

Even with all this, the controller method does not get the value. It is allways zero.

What to do?

My form looks like so:

```
 <form action="@Url.Action("Temperature","Api")" method="post" >
       <input type="number" name=" " step="0.25"/>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" />
   </form>
</div>

<script>
    $("form").submit(function () {
        $(this).children('[name="submit"]').remove();
    });
</script>
```

The controller:

```
    // POST: api/Temperature
    public void Post([FromBody]double value) //FormDataCollection data
    {            
        Temperature newEntry = new Temperature() { Timestamp = DateTime.Now, Value = value};
        try
        {
            db.Temperatures.Add(newEntry);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You need to set name attribute of the input. Otherwise how the post action would know which input to consider as value? Also step attribute of input won't be considered by the server code for sure.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya - According to the content on the attached link, sending simple types should send ONE parameter only and therefore the name must be empty - '**=value**'. Otherwise I should send data as complex type and make a model for it on serverside.

**Edit** Citation from link: _Specifically, the name portion of the name/value pair must be empty for a simple type._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Ajax...

Change your Html little bit like this:

```
 <div>
       <input type="number" id="number" name=" " step="0.25"/>
       <input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" />
</div>
```

Then:

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit', function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ControllerName/Post',
        data: {
            value: JSON.stringify($('#number').val())
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("An Issue has occured");
        }
    });
})
```

Also your controller input parameters would be like:

```
public void Post([FromBody]string value) //convert string to double later within method
```

Comment: It works with AJAX, I am only a bit bothered because it does not work with plain HTML tags and attributes, but you need to use jQuery for this.